# What does this part in code mean? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Hey guys im new to java and i came across this thing
Ok so here i got something i just cant comprehend

here i have this class:

```
class FailSoftArray {

    private int a[]; // reference to array
    private int errval; 
    public int length; 

    public FailSoftArray(int size, int errv) {
        a = new int[size];
        errval = errv;
        length = size;
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        if(indexOK(index)) return a[index];
        return errval;
    }

    public boolean put(int index, int val) {
        if(indexOK(index)) {
            a[index] = val;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean indexOK(int index) {
        if(index >= 0 & index < length) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

What does `indexOK(index)` mean? What does it do?

Comment: it checks whether the index is valid incase it throws a `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: It calls `indexOK`, with the parameter being the value of `index`, and does something if the return value is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method to determine if the index its going to get in the array is valid.

Normally, if a value less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array was used as an index, it would cause an error, throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since an array is indexed from `0` to `length - 1`.

The method avoids that possible outcome by ensuring the index will always be valid before using it, and it does this by comparing the index to see if it's `>= 0`, then comparing `< length`, then the `&` makes sure **both** are true (if both conditions are true, it can be used as an index to the array without throwing an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

When you call indexOK, your program runs the following method, with an index as an argument:

```
private boolean indexOK(int index) {
if(index >= 0 & index < length) return true;
return false;
}
}
```

indexOK returns a boolean value, so the result is either true or false. When is the result true?

```
if(index >= 0 & index < length) return true;
return false;
```

If the argument is larger than or equal to zero AND the argument is less than length, the result is true. Otherwise, the result is false.

The purpose of indexOK is to check whether or not a value is an appropriate index for an array. A negative index is invalid, as is an index which equals or exceeds the length of the array it references. So the check

```
index >= 0
```

determines whether or not the index is negative, and the check

```
index < length
```

determines whether or not the index equals or exceeds the length of the array it references.

Answer (score -2):

Let me rewrite the method in a way that is more understandable:

```
    private boolean indexOK(int index) {
        if(index >= 0 & index < length) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The method will return true, when the value of index is atleast 0 and smaller than length at the same time. You can use an if-statement without its curly brackets, but it will only use the following line as the 'inner block'. This is a rather bad practice, since it's a little unclear. Furthermore, it can be easily the cause of unwanted bugs and errors, since adding lines to the 'inner block' without adding curly brackets around them isn't that uncommon. In my humble opinion, 1 line (or 2 brackets) more of code isn't that much and one should always add them.